# How to plot spheres in 3d with plotly (or another library)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, plotly

I am struggling with plotting something, that I thought should be really simple. I have a dataframe/table `df` that contains the coordinates x,y,z of spheres. Additionally, in a separate column, it contains the radius of these spheres. How can I make with plotly a 3d plot of the spheres in space with their correct radius being used?

The closest I have come to making this plot reality is this code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x =y=z = np.arange(1,4)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(
        mode='markers',
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z,
        marker=dict(color=px.colors.qualitative.D3,size=[50, 5, 25],sizemode='diameter'
        )
    )
)
```

This produces almost what I want (see below), but notice that the sizes of the spheres are not correct - the ratios between the sphere sizes are correct, but I want `size` to provide the absolute size of the spheres in the plot. How can I make this plot work with plotly (or worst case with another library)? Tnx!

[image]

Comment: Using `diameter` sets the size of the marker _in pixels_. I don't know plotly, but matplotlib, but I doubt you can set the marker size in axis units

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use markers, the size is usually specified in pixels (either area or diameter). The docs state [precisely that](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter3d/#scatter3d-marker-sizemode).

I have never used `plotly`, but I am pretty sure it will be easy to convert this script using `matplotlib` to use `plotly` (see [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/surface/).)

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import repeat  # just for the example

def makesphere(x, y, z, radius, resolution=10):
    """Return the coordinates for plotting a sphere centered at (x,y,z)"""
    u, v = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:resolution*2j, 0:np.pi:resolution*1j]
    X = radius * np.cos(u)*np.sin(v) + x
    Y = radius * np.sin(u)*np.sin(v) + y
    Z = radius * np.cos(v) + z
    return (X, Y, Z)

fig = plt.figure("Spheres")
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

for x, y, z, radius, in zip(*repeat(np.arange(1,4),3), [.1, .5, .75]):
    X, Y, Z = makesphere(x, y, z, radius)
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, color="r")
```

Result:

[image: Result of the script]

If you want smoother spheres, increase the `resolution` parameter (and check the  `cstride` and `rstride` parameters to `plot_surface`).

Comment: Thanks! And do you know if I can make the spheres semi-transparent, is there something like an `alpha`-parameter for that? I am asking, because some small spheres might be inside larger spheres and I want to be able to see that. I will wait for another day or so if someone else will post a plotly solution to this problem. If no one does, I will accept your post as a solution. Thanks again!

Comment: You can set the alpha value. See valid color specifications [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colors.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It reminded me to accept your post as the answer to my question. Based on your post I also figured out how to do the plot in `plotly`, I will include it as an alternative answer here, too

Answer (score 3):

Based on azelcer's answer I managed to produce the following code that plots spheres with `plotly`:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def ms(x, y, z, radius, resolution=20):
    """Return the coordinates for plotting a sphere centered at (x,y,z)"""
    u, v = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:resolution*2j, 0:np.pi:resolution*1j]
    X = radius * np.cos(u)*np.sin(v) + x
    Y = radius * np.sin(u)*np.sin(v) + y
    Z = radius * np.cos(v) + z
    return (X, Y, Z)

df = pd.read_csv('xyzr_sphere_coordinates.txt')

data = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    (x_pns_surface, y_pns_surface, z_pns_suraface) = ms(row.x, row.y, row.z, row.r)
    data.append(go.Surface(x=x_pns_surface, y=y_pns_surface, z=z_pns_suraface, opacity=0.5))

fig = go.Figure(data=data)
fig.show()
```

It leads to this 3d interactive figure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I personally do the mesh of the sphere as an isosurface with **PyVista**, and I use `go.Mesh3d` to plot it with **plotly**.

```py
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio # to save the graphics as html

# center 
x0 = 0
y0 = 0
z0 = 0
# radius 
r = 2
# radius + 2% to be sure of the bounds
R = r * 1.02

def f(x, y, z):
    return (
        (x-x0)**2 + (y-y0)**2 + (z-z0)**2
    )

# generate data grid for computing the values
X, Y, Z = np.mgrid[(-R+x0):(R+x0):250j, (-R+y0):(R+y0):250j, (-R+z0):(R+z0):250j]
# create a structured grid
grid = pv.StructuredGrid(X, Y, Z)
# compute and assign the values
values = f(X, Y, Z)
grid.point_data["values"] = values.ravel(order = "F")
# compute the isosurface f(x, y, z) = r²
isosurf = grid.contour(isosurfaces = [r**2])
mesh = isosurf.extract_geometry()
# extract vertices and triangles
vertices = mesh.points
triangles = mesh.faces.reshape(-1, 4)

# plot
fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Mesh3d(
        x=vertices[:, 0],
        y=vertices[:, 1],
        z=vertices[:, 2],
        colorscale = [[0, 'gold'],
                     [0.5, 'mediumturquoise'],
                     [1, 'magenta']],
        # Intensity of each vertex, which will be interpolated and color-coded
        intensity = np.linspace(0, 1, len(vertices)),
        # i, j and k give the vertices of the triangles
        i = triangles[:, 1],
        j = triangles[:, 2],
        k = triangles[:, 3],
        showscale = False
    )
])

fig.show()

# save
pio.write_html(fig, "plotlySphere.html")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Plots of spheres may be directly constructed using the SphericalSurface class in [S3Dlib](https://s3dlib.org/).  For example:

[image: spheres]

which was generated from the script:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import s3dlib.surface as s3d

csv_data = []
with open('testdata.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader: csv_data.append(row)    
# note: first row contains the column labels
geom = np.array([ c[0:4] for c in csv_data ][1:]).astype(float)  # xyz & radii
colors =        [   c[4] for c in csv_data ][1:]

rez=3
for i,sph in enumerate(geom) :
    s = s3d.SphericalSurface(rez,color=colors[i]).domain(sph[3])
    s.transform(translate=sph[0:3])
    spheres = s if i==0 else spheres+s

fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
s3d.auto_scale(ax,spheres, rscale=True )
ax.add_collection3d(spheres.shade())

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The csv datafile was generated using Excel with random xyz coordinates in [-25,25].  A normal distribution was used for the radii with a mean of 10 and standard deviation of 5.  Random colors were taken from Matplotlib named [CSS colors](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html#css-colors).

An additional example of using spherical surface objects to create a figure is shown below:

[image]

For this case, sphere position, size  and color are explicitly defined.  The [code](https://s3dlib.org/examples/composite/nacl.html) is provided in the S3Dlib documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and welcome to the StackOverflow community!

Answer (score 1):

Posting this in case it's helpful!

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go


d = np.pi/32

theta, phi = np.mgrid[0:np.pi+d:d, 0:2*np.pi:d]
# Convert to Cartesian coordinates
x = np.sin(theta) * np.cos(phi)
y = np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi)
z = np.cos(theta)
# print(x.shape, y.shape, z.shape)  # (33, 64) (33, 64) (33, 64)
points = np.vstack([x.ravel(), y.ravel(), z.ravel()])
# print(points.shape)  # (3, 2112)
x, y, z = points
# print(x.shape, y.shape, z.shape)  # (2112,) (2112,) (2112,)

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Mesh3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, color='lightpink', opacity=0.50, alphahull=0)
])
fig.update_traces(lighting=dict(ambient=0.5, specular=1.0))
```

[image: plotly figure of unit sphere]